# using http persistant is slower than non persistant

Tags: python, python-requests

I have set up a http server using simplehttpserver. I have 2 clients using the requests library. Both request for 100 files consecutively. One uses persistent, the other uses non-persistent. The files sent is small about 20 bytes each. The total time is calculated. Result: The non-persistent is faster than the persistent 9/10 times.  Is there an explanation for this?

Sample code
Server:

```
Handler = SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler
Handler.protocol_version = "HTTP/1.1" 
httpd = SocketServer.TCPServer(("", 8000), Handler)
httpd.serve_forever()
```

Client:

```
header = {"Connection" : "close"} #remove for persistant
s = requests.session()
response = sess.get((url) + filename, headers=header)
```

Comment: Can you provide some samples of your code?

Answer (score 0):

I'm unable to reproduce this (Python 3.7).

With a `Connection: close` header, I get about 25% slower RPS.

## server.py

```
import socketserver
import http.server

PORT = 8000
Handler = http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler
Handler.protocol_version = "HTTP/1.1" 
httpd = socketserver.TCPServer(("", PORT), Handler)
httpd.serve_forever()
```

## client.py

```
import requests
import time

def test(headers, n=1500):
    with requests.session() as sess:
        t0 = time.time()
        for x in range(n):
            assert sess.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/server.py', headers=headers).content
        t1 = time.time()
        print(headers, n / (t1 - t0), 'rps')

test({})
test({"Connection": "close"})
test({"Connection": "keep-alive"})
```

```
$ python3 client.py
{} 514.4191683333725 rps
{'Connection': 'close'} 424.7938184319337 rps
{'Connection': 'keep-alive'} 492.5251360628307 rps
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why but when I ran it I got the following result

```
$ python3 client.py{} 22.51256576012429 rps
{'Connection': 'close'} 320.24445743902817 rps
{'Connection': 'keep-alive'} 22.209050176933395 rps
```